# Translating SQL Server 'OUTPUT' to Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am having big issues translating my MSSQL (sql-server) query to Oracle (PL-SQL).

The goal is to do an update and a select on the updated field in one threadsafe operation.

My current MSSQL query:

```
UPDATE PDFCONVERT_G
SET PDF_STATUS = 1, PDF_STARTDATE = GETDATE(), PDF_CONVERTERNAME='inputConverterName'
OUTPUT Inserted.PDF_ACTION as Action,
       Inserted.PDF_ARKMERK_VE As ARKMERK, 
       Inserted.PDF_TYPE_DL as DlTypeDT, 
       Inserted.PDF_DOKID_VE as DocId, 
       Inserted.PDF_DOKMALID_VE as DOKMALID, 
       Inserted.PDF_FILREF_VE as FILREF, 
       Inserted.PDF_FILTYPE_LF as Filtype,
       Inserted.PDF_JPID_JP as JpId, 
       Inserted.PDF_LOCFILREF_VE as LOCFILREF, 
       Inserted.PDF_SAID_SA as SaId, 
       Inserted.PDF_SJEKKETUT_VE as SJEKKETUT, 
       Inserted.PDF_TGKODE_VE as TGKODE, 
       Inserted.PDF_VARIANT_VE as Variant, 
       Inserted.PDF_VERSJON_VE as Version, 
       Inserted.PDF_CHECKINAFTERCONVERT as CheckinAfterConvert
FROM PDFCONVERT_G t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM PDFCONVERT_G A WHERE (
        (A.PDF_LAGRENH_VE = 'PROD' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PDFCONVERT_G B WHERE A.PDF_JOBID=B.PDF_JOBID AND B.PDF_LAGRENH_VE='PROD' AND B.PDF_ACTION='MERGE')) 
        AND PDF_STATUS = 0 AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM PDFCONVERT_G B where a.pdf_jobid = b.pdf_jobid and b.pdf_status > 0 and a.pdf_action != b.pdf_action)) 
    ORDER BY A.PDF_PRIORITY DESC, A.PDF_JOBID, A.PDF_RNR
    ) t2 ON t2.PDF_JOBID = t1.PDF_JOBID
```

I can simply do this query in my .net code and the result will be the Output variables.

I know Oracle has the RETURNING INTO syntax but concidering how complex my WHERE clause is I simply get syntax errors all the time.

I would prefer to write a query without creating a function but even if I have to do that, I am having issues.

Comment: What syntax errors? Where is the code? Why do you assume that the `WHERE` statement have anything to do with `RETURNING INTO`? In any case try to simplify the statement first, *then* try to translate it. Eg why `INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1....)` instead of `t1.PDF_JOBID IN (SELECT PDF_JOBID FROM ...)`? Why the multiple nested subqueries? You can also use CTEs in both databases to simplify the statement

Comment: I am new to sql and I did not write the query, so how exactly would you simplify it? It is not so clear to me what you are refering to. Also, how can I rewrite from the INNER JOIN? I do need that TOP(1) as the result of the inner join returns multiple rows. The problem I have with RETURNING INTO is that I need oracle variables to store that into. I just want to return the values to the .net code like the MSSQL query does, I don't want them in oracle variables first.

Comment: Do it for a simple query and add complexity step by step. Show the code and the errors. Rrread http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language (similar to SQL Server's T-SQL) - this question is nothing to do with PL/SQL as it is entirely SQL.

Comment: @MT0: the question is somehow about PL/SQL because that's the only way to use a `returning into`. But there is no equivalent to SQL Server's `OUTPUT` clause in Oracle. The `returning into` is the closest thing to that but only works for single rows if I am not mistaken (and _requires_ the use of a PL/SQL block and you still can't see that as a "result set")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The OP is talking about his `.net` code - so he can call the statement without a PL/SQL anonymous block and map the `RETURNING ... INTO ...` values to the bind parameters of the called statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM PDFCONVERT_G A
WHERE (
    (   A.PDF_LAGRENH_VE = 'PROD'
     OR EXISTS(SELECT *
               FROM   PDFCONVERT_G B
               WHERE  A.PDF_JOBID=B.PDF_JOBID
               AND    B.PDF_LAGRENH_VE='PROD'
               AND    B.PDF_ACTION='MERGE')
    ) 
    AND PDF_STATUS = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM   PDFCONVERT_G B
        where  a.pdf_jobid = b.pdf_jobid
        and    b.pdf_status > 0
        and    a.pdf_action != b.pdf_action
    )
) 
ORDER BY A.PDF_PRIORITY DESC, A.PDF_JOBID, A.PDF_RNR
```

Can be rewritten (without the correlated sub-queries) as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY PDF_PRIORITY DESC, PDF_JOBID, PDF_RNR ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT a.*,
           COUNT(
             CASE WHEN DF_LAGRENH_VE = 'PROD'
                  AND  PDF_ACTION    = 'MERGE'
                  THEN 1 END
           ) OVER ( PARTITION BY pdf_jobid )
             AS num_prod_merge,
           COUNT(
             CASE WHEN pdf_status > 0 THEN 1 END
           ) OVER ( PARTITION BY pdf_jobid )
             AS num_all_actions,
           COUNT(
             CASE WHEN pdf_status > 0 THEN 1 END
           ) OVER ( PARTITION BY pdf_jobid, pdf_action )
             AS num_same_actions
    FROM   PDFCONVERT_G a
  ) a
  WHERE  ( PDF_LAGRENH_VE = 'PROD' OR num_prod_merge > 0 )
  AND    PDF_STATUS = 0
  AND    num_all_actions = num_same_actions
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

You can then rewrite your `UPDATE` to something like:

```
UPDATE PDFCONVERT_G
SET PDF_STATUS       = 1,
    PDF_STARTDATE    = SYSDATE,
    PDF_CONVERTERNAME='inputConverterName'
WHERE ROWID = (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    -- as above
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
RETURNING PDF_ACTION -- , ...
INTO      :Action    -- , ...
```

*(Note: Unable to test this at the moment so there may be some small syntax errors but you should get the general idea.)*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The where clause is restricting it to a single row. The OP is using `TOP(1)` and, converting to Oracle, I've used `ROW_NUMBER()`.